# How do I create dynamic paths in Grapevine

Tags: grapevine

I'm trying to create a RESTFUL API using Grapevine.
I would like to create dynamic paths e.g.

```
[RestRoute(PathInfo = "api/eshare/getcustomersbyname/{namepart}", HttpMethod = HttpMethod.GET)]
```

Purpose is to Search all customers where {namepart} is present and return json.

When I enter http://localhost:2000/api/eshare/getcustomersbyname/bio in the browser I always get: `Route not Found for GET api/eshare/getcustomersbyname`

Thx for the help

Answer (score 0):

You're really close. Use square brackets instead of curly braces in your pattern.

```
[RestRoute(PathInfo = "api/eshare/getcustomersbyname/[namepart]", HttpMethod = HttpMethod.GET)]
```

**Update**: Grapevine 4.x and lower used square brackets for route parameters. Grapevine 5+ uses the curly braces (just like asp.net)